# Run bash command on aws instance using fog

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, fog

I am using [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) to launch an instance on aws. Here is an example:

```
server = fog.servers.create(
 :image_id=>'ami-id',
 :flavor_id=>'t2.micro',
 :key_name => 'key',
 )
```

I have a 'server' object which represents my instance, and now I need to run a bash command or script on my instance. How can I do it via fog?

Comment: Did you try `server.ssh('pwd')`? ... or `server.ssh(['uname', 'whoami'])` as samples ... I would try that, if it works tell us, and if it does not work, come back with your findings and someone "in the know" will help, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, I found out how to use `ssh` method properly!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it, firstly we should add our instance username (on aws default is *ubuntu*) and path to your key file:

```
server.username = 'ubuntu'
server.private_key_path = '/path/to/key/Key.pem'
```

Then, we finally can use `ssh` method:

`server.ssh("your command")`